# complex SQL INSERT not working

Tags: t-sql, insert, pivot, pivot-table, unpivot

I am working on migrating data from 1 row by X columns in one table to X rows in another table. In the first table, multiple boolean records `AF.AdditionalFieldsBoolean15` (and 14, 13, 12, etc) are stored in a single row. I need to create a single row to represent each 'true' boolean column.

I have been working with the following code, which executes flawlessly, except that it only inserts 1 record. When I run the SELECT statement in the second code block, I return 12 records. How do I ensure that I am iterating over all records?

```
BEGIN TRAN TEST

DECLARE @id uniqueidentifier = NEWID()
DECLARE @dest uniqueidentifier = 'AC34C8E5-8859-4E74-ACF2-54B3804AE9C9'
DECLARE @person uniqueidentifier

SELECT @person = GP.Oid FROM <Redacted>.GenericPerson AS GP

INNER JOIN <Redacted>.AdditionalFields AS AF
ON GP.AdditionalFields = AF.Oid

WHERE AF.AdditionalBoolean15 = 'true'

INSERT INTO <Redacted>.Referral (Oid, Destination, Person)
OUTPUT INSERTED.*
VALUES (@id, @dest, @person)
```

Select statement that returns 12 records

```
SELECT *
FROM WS_Live.dbo.GenericPerson AS GP
INNER JOIN WS_Live.dbo.AdditionalFields AS AF
ON GP.AdditionalFields = AF.Oid

WHERE AF.AdditionalBoolean15 = 'true'
```

|

|

|

|

|

|

--------------SOLUTION (EDIT)--------------------

Thanks to M.Ali I was able to muddle through pivot tables and worked out the following solution. Just wanted to post with some explanation in case anyone needs this in the future.

```
INSERT INTO <Redacted>.Referral (Person, Destination, Oid)
OUTPUT INSERTED.*
SELECT   Person
       , Destination
       , NEWID() AS Oid
FROM     
(
    SELECT 
    GP.Oid AS Person, 
    AF.AdditionalBoolean15 AS 'AC34C8E5-8859-4E74-ACF2-54B3804AE9C9', 
    AF.AdditionalBoolean14 AS '7DE4B414-42E0-4E39-9432-6DC9F60A5512',
    AF.AdditionalBoolean8  AS '5760A126-AD15-4FF4-B608-F1C4220C7087',
    AF.AdditionalBoolean13 AS '4EFFB0FB-BB6C-4425-9653-D482B6C827AC',
    AF.AdditionalBoolean17 AS '0696C571-EEFA-4FE6-82DA-4FF6AB96CC98',
    AF.AdditionalBoolean4  AS 'FF381D63-A76C-46F1-8E2C-E2E3C69365BF',
    AF.AdditionalBoolean20 AS 'C371E419-4E34-4F46-B07D-A4533491D944',
    AF.AdditionalBoolean16 AS '1F0D1221-76D7-4F1F-BB7A-818BB26E0590',
    AF.AdditionalBoolean18 AS 'C6FD53A8-37B9-4519-A825-472722A158C9',
    AF.AdditionalBoolean19 AS 'BEBD6ED6-AF0A-4A05-A1C1-060B2926F83E'

    FROM <Redacted>.GenericPerson GP
    INNER JOIN <Redacted>.AdditionalFields AF
    ON GP.AdditionalFields = AF.Oid 

)AS cp

UNPIVOT 
( 
    Bool FOR Destination IN ([AC34C8E5-8859-4E74-ACF2-54B3804AE9C9],
                             [7DE4B414-42E0-4E39-9432-6DC9F60A5512],
                             [5760A126-AD15-4FF4-B608-F1C4220C7087],
                             [4EFFB0FB-BB6C-4425-9653-D482B6C827AC],
                             [0696C571-EEFA-4FE6-82DA-4FF6AB96CC98],
                             [FF381D63-A76C-46F1-8E2C-E2E3C69365BF],
                             [C371E419-4E34-4F46-B07D-A4533491D944],
                             [1F0D1221-76D7-4F1F-BB7A-818BB26E0590],
                             [C6FD53A8-37B9-4519-A825-472722A158C9],
                             [BEBD6ED6-AF0A-4A05-A1C1-060B2926F83E]) 
)AS up

WHERE Bool = 'true'
ORDER BY Person, Destination
```

First of all, I'm not sure why this `SELECT NEWID()` at the top worked, where I have received errors when trying to `SELECT NEWID()` before.

I felt a little creative about using statements like 
`AF.AdditionalBoolean19 AS 'BEBD6ED6-AF0A-4A05-A1C1-060B2926F83E'` 
because the table I was inserting into required a GUID from another table that represented a plaintext 'Name'. There is no table linking each column name to that GUID, so I think this was the best way, but I would like to hear if anyone can think of a better way.

Comment: why are you doing this one row at a time?  Is there a specific requirement there...it seems you would be better off inserting all 12 rows at once   (Oh, points for a great name!)

Comment: Thanks!! I'm trying to do all 12 at once, but I think I'm doing something wrong because it is only performing for one row.

Comment: You basically need an `UNPIVOT` query to unpivot your `AdditionalBooleanN` columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A demo how you can unpivot your `AdditionalBooleanN` columns and rather then doing it row by row just use where clause to filter result and insert into intended destination tables.

### Test Data

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE 
       (ID INT , dest INT, Person INT, Bol1 INT, Bol2 INT, Bol3 INT)
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES 
(1 , 100 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1) ,
(2 , 200 , 2 , 1 , 1 , 0) ,
(3 , 300 , 3 , 1 , 0 , 0) ,
(4 , 400 , 4 , 0 , 0 , 0)
```

### Query

```
-- INSERT INTO Destination_Table (ID , Dest, Person, bol_Column)
SELECT *                     --<-- Only select columns that needs to be inserted 
FROM @TABLE t
 UNPIVOT ( Value FOR Bool_Column IN (Bol1, Bol2, Bol3) )up
-- WHERE  Bool_Column  = ??
```

### Result

```
╔════╦══════╦════════╦═══════╦═════════════╗
║ ID ║ dest ║ Person ║ Value ║ Bool_Column ║
╠════╬══════╬════════╬═══════╬═════════════╣
║  1 ║  100 ║      1 ║     1 ║ Bol1        ║
║  1 ║  100 ║      1 ║     1 ║ Bol2        ║
║  1 ║  100 ║      1 ║     1 ║ Bol3        ║
║  2 ║  200 ║      2 ║     1 ║ Bol1        ║
║  2 ║  200 ║      2 ║     1 ║ Bol2        ║
║  2 ║  200 ║      2 ║     0 ║ Bol3        ║
║  3 ║  300 ║      3 ║     1 ║ Bol1        ║
║  3 ║  300 ║      3 ║     0 ║ Bol2        ║
║  3 ║  300 ║      3 ║     0 ║ Bol3        ║
║  4 ║  400 ║      4 ║     0 ║ Bol1        ║
║  4 ║  400 ║      4 ║     0 ║ Bol2        ║
║  4 ║  400 ║      4 ║     0 ║ Bol3        ║
╚════╩══════╩════════╩═══════╩═════════════╝
```

Comment: Could I use `(@id, @dest, @person)` for the first three columns? And, could I select `AddtionalFieldsBooleanN` from `<Redacted>.AdditionalFields`, so something like `(@id, @dest, @person, AdditionalFieldsBoolean1, AdditionalFieldsBoolean2, AdditionalFieldsBoolean3)` ?

Comment: yes you can use `SELECT @id, @dest, @person, AddtionalFieldsBooleanN` from table when inserting rows into tables.

Comment: I think I'm confused because I need "ID" to be a GUID, I'm selecting "Destination" from a table that is NOT where my boolean values are stored, and I don't need to record the boolean value. I haven't been able to do a `SELECT` statement that incorporates NEWID()